# How do i restore git push -f without git pull from remote repo?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, git-revert

Local repository A(branch feature/2.0 on A) in my system, i did git remote add associated with a remote repository B  (branch main)
`git add remote repository B`
and then nothing changed, direct git push -f push local repository A to the remote associated repository B, now the associated remote repository B is overwritten by the local repository A content
`git push -f global main`
how to restore the content of the associated remote repository B,i have executed
`git reflog --oneline`
`git reset --hard <commit-hash>`
`git push -f origin main`
and repository B content is still overwritten by repository A,i want to restore repository B

Comment: Which repos are associated with the remotes `global` and `origin`?

Comment: Not yet,My repo A associated with the remotess `global`

Comment: i try `git reflog show remotes/origin/main` and it shows `25e8c88 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, global/main, main) remotes/origin/main@{0}: update by push` and `5e364c6 (HEAD -> feature/2.0) remotes/origin/main@{1}: pull: fast-forward`

Comment: and then i try to executed `git reset --hard remotes/origin/main@{1}` and `git push -f global main` but it doesn't work and return "Everything up-to-date".

Answer (score 0):

i went back to my old local repo B and try `git push -f`  then it works.it will force update local to remote origin main